# How to get all user list group by location in postgres sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

| username | location |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | L1 |
| user2 | L2 |
| user3 | L2 |
| user4 | L3 |
| user5 | L4 |

I need the final output

L1 - ['user1']

L2 - ['user2', 'user3']

L3 - ['user4']

L4 - ['user5']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `array_agg` in postgres:

```
select location , array_agg(username)
from table
group by location
```

alternatively you can use `string_agg(username,',')` if you want comma separated string instead of list

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c18b9e2f0ae3d248e01056f197863ca9)*